# Расположение букв на клавиатуре — какой принцип?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Может быть, не совсем по теме вопрос, но меня всегда озадачивало: по какому принципу расположены на компьютерной клавиатуре русские буквы и почему они не совпадают с английскими? Признаться, некоторые буквы расположены так, что кажется, что их поставили рядом только ради смеха, такие забавные опечатки получаются (особенно З и Х, Д и Ж и П и Р).)))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раскладку придумали в США в конце XIX века (в России производство собственных пишущих машинок было налажено только к 1930-м годам). Конструкция печатающего узла была достаточно отработана, и важнейшие буквы расположили под указательными пальцами — в отличие от QWERTY. В то время раскладка официально называлась «стандард-клавиатура»[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IFQQ.jpg). До середины 50-х годов XX века русскую раскладку вернее было называть ЙІУКЕН, так как после реформы орфографии, когда, в частности, из алфавита был исключен ряд букв, раскладка приняла современный вид не сразу.[источник не указан 128 дней] Буквы Ц и Э размещались среди цифр, а цифры 0, 1 и 3 вообще отсутствовали, так как считалось, что их можно заменить буквами О, І и З.

Экономия некоторых символов и букв была распространённой традицией, которая прослеживалась с момента создания пишущих машинок. В русских раскладках зачастую экономили букву Ё, точку с запятой, звёздочку, скобки. При этом часть знаков заменялась внешне схожими, как это было с цифрами 0, 1, 3; другую часть получали так называемым «составным методом», заключавшимся в том, что несколько знаков печатались друг поверх друга.
Картинка:

[image]

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Underwood.jpg
(Вики)

Впрочем, в отношении продуманности раскладки йцукен есть и иные мнения. В частности, считается, что средний, наиболее удобный ряд клавиатуры задействован меньше, чем это в принципе можно было достичь, поэтому приходится чаще, чем следовало бы, гнуть пальцы. Кроме того, многие авторы (Артемий Лебедев, например) указывают на непродуманность расположения точки и запятой. Их надо хотя бы местами поменять. Запятая на верхнем регистре - глупость.

Comment: Вот насчет запятой - особенно согласна! А еще я мучаюсь из-за отсутствия в русской раскладке апострофа. Понятно, что в русском языке его нет, но ведь приходится всякие слова набирать. Те же французские фамилии типа д'Артаньян. Приходится переключаться на английский ради апострофа. А если на клавиатуре не две раскладки, а, например, три, как у нас на Украине!

Answer (score 6):

Буквы на клавиатуре компьютера расположены так же, как они располагались на клавиатуре печатных машинок: по принципу наибольшей повторяемости. Например, в русских словах часто встречаются гласные буквы О, Е, И, А и согласные Н, Т, С, Р . Клавиши с этими буквами расположены в центре. Да и буквы рядом тоже этому принципу подчиняются (повторяемость сочетаний).  Например, внизу рядом идут буквы ИТЬ, как на конце глаголов.

Comment: Единственное замечание, что в той же английской раскладке буквы расположены наоборот - в смысле, чтобы замедлить набор текста. Я про qwerty/qwertz. Существует еще раскладка Дворака, в которой буквы распределены именно по статистике их нахождения в тексте. Ну, и для кириллицы есть фонетическая раскладка, когда каждой латинской букве ставится в соответствие одна кириллическая. Например, a-а, b-б, c-ц и т.д.

Comment: Недавно читала статью на эту тему, но, к сожалению, не нашла ее сейчас. Интересно , что первоначально был алфавитный порядок букв. Похожая статья http://allforchildren.ru/why/why69.php
Не знаю, можно ли так добавлять ссылки.

Comment: >Единственное замечание, что в той же английской раскладке буквы расположены наоборот  
  
Вы серьезно?

Comment: >Да и буквы рядом тоже этому принципу подчиняются (повторяемость сочетаний). Например, внизу рядом идут буквы ИТЬ,   
  
Скорее всего - случайное совпадение.
Более того, две подряд клавиши, набираемые одним пальцем скорее всего создают сложности, а не упрощают. Особенно таким людям как я - у которых не все пальцы одинаково хорошо слушаются.